# Unable To Load Helper Functions in (Laravel7) After Successful Deployment

Tags: laravel-7, php-7.4

Api Framework : Laravel7
Server : AWS ( OD ) Instance
Deployment Tool : Jenkins

We do deploy code on AWS OD instances, but sometime after clear app cache also clear compiled files. in some case function's aren't available in controllers/model

Generally i do run the following set of command

```
php artisan config:cache // clearing config cache 
php artisan clear-compiled // clearing compiled cache
```

in some of the cases, those helper function changes doesn't affect the controller scope or functions not available to use.

those function's should be there even after clearing app cache too. and all of the changes we made in helper function should be available in application scope , as helper functions stands for.

Comment: php artisan config:clear && composer dump-autoload